# Image capture the center of the screen using python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

How to capture the center of the screen using python I tried this code but it gives me error whenever I up my value for the parameters above 200.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

while(True):
    printscreen_pil =  ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,200,500,200))
    printscreen_numpy =   np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')\
    .reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1],printscreen_pil.size[0],3)) 
    cv2.imshow('window',printscreen_numpy)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Add a sample image to the question and output of the capture to show what you mean center of the screen image. OP should describe the problem explicitly to avoid any guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a wander that you are getting anything.
You have both Y's of the same value. At the moment, your bounding box is zero pixels high. I.e. You have a line going from (0, 200) to (500, 200). (if it can be called a line).

Put in your code the following line:

```
print printscreen_pil.size
```

and you will see.

The bounding box is described with top left corner of a rectangle and the bottom right corner of the same rectangle.

So, your bounding box should be for example:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
x1 = 0; y1 = 200
x2 = 500; y2 = 500
# If you want center of a screen then calculate them according to the screen's size.
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

Screen's size you can get directly from OS or get the whole screen first, and then crop out the area you want.

```
img = ImageGrab.grab()
size = img.size
x1 = size[0]/2-100; y1= size[1]/2-100
x2 = x1+200; y2 = y1+200
portion = img.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
```